# Windows or computer slowing down, programs not responding, browsers not loading?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, freeze, microsoft-powerpoint, task-manager

Working with Windows 8. I think this may be a network issue but I don't know how to check to confirm. I am working on a powerpoint that is saved to a network location. I can open and edit it just fine, but saving takes forever and bar pops up that never actually loads all the way. If I cancel the save, it stops responding. Google chrome also is slow to load (I only have it working now because I just restarted) and eventually doesn't respond when I try to exit out. Even the task manager will not cooperate and won't end tasks and also eventually stops responding.

Nothing pops up saying that my computer is disconnected from the internet or the network, so I'm not sure what's going. Twice so far I've hard to hard restart (press and hold the power button) because the computer won't actually restart itself, it just keeps loading and loading on the restart page. After I turn the computer back on, programs and browsers work fine up until I open something and try to save it.

If anybody else had dealt with something like this or knows how I could check to see what's wrong I would greatly appreciate it. This is a work computer so I would rather avoid (and probably don't have permission) to download specific programs, so an internal solution would probably be easiest.

Comment: did you try booting in safe mode?

Comment: @RookieTEC9 would you mind explaining how to do that? I'll give it a shot and update on how it goes.

Comment: When booting up the computer, press F8, F12, or 'DEL', repeatedly until the computer boots.

Comment: Idea: Is there a network location that is mapped and no longer exists? If yes, try to disconnect it.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Ever since windows 8's fastboot, you can no longer boot using F8.

Comment: Use advanced startup or cause Windows 8 and above to fail to load 3 times

Comment: Ok I tried booting in safe mode and then rebooting in "regular mode". Powerpoint and other programs are opening and editing fine but I'll try saving in a few minutes and seeing how that goes. If it doesn't go well I'll post back on here hopefully with more details. if not, thank you for all the input!

Comment: Does this happen in save mode? Stick around in safe mode a bit.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 it's working now in regular mode so I don't want to mess with it in safe mode. If I have the problem again I'll stick around in safe mode for a bit longer and see how that goes. Safe mode seemed to disconnect me from the network though, so I'm not sure I'd even be able to open it.

Comment: Okay. Please update if anything happens.